# Why does the back button break parts of my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-history

I am building an app with server-side routing and react/redux as the front end framework.

One of my react components is a search component that renders results based on search parameters in the URL. When I update the search, the url parameters also update via `window.history.pushState`.

But when I click the back button, parts of my app are exhibiting strange behavior. The search results component reloads as a browser cache and loses all of its react/redux functionality. The search bar, however, retains its react/redux functionality.

I tried intercepting the event with componentWillUnmount, but the back button doesn't cause React to fully unmount.

I tried intercepting the back button via `popstate` but there is no way to prevent default with the popstate event. There's also no event that detects when the cache finishes loading after you hit the back button.

I am assuming that React has a solution for this but I haven't been able to find it.

Is there a way to solve this in an app without React router?

To be clear, the issue is that my app loses its React/redux functionality when I hit the back button.

Comment: Are you using react-router?

Comment: No, like I said, the routing is server-side

Comment: It's possible that there are multiple `pushState` happening in your app. Find them and try using `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent it from bubbling up the chain.

Comment: You need to show us your code in which you're intercepting the event. We can't debug it without seeing it

Comment: Thanks @shriek, I think you were right. It was a stray popstate handler in another part of the app